# echoing multiple variables with the variables containing muliple columns of data ; bash

Tags: bash, awk

ok, so first to explain the problem i am having in more detail. i am setting two variables here; one to copy one column of data  and another to copy multiple columns of data...

the issue is that i want to append the first column of data infront of the multiple columns while keeping them aligned

the loops do what i want them too when i redirect them to Cmain individually; but i need to do it to both of them

```
#copies first column of original car file to format the atom numbers

 FC=$(awk '{for (i=6; i<=21 ; i++)
 if (NR >= 6 && NR == i)
      print $1}' $carf)


 #copies and formats  the rest of the columns from the .incoor file and sets to variable Col

 col=$(awk '{for (j=6; j <= 21 ; j++)
 if (NR >= 6 && NR == j)
 printf  "%13.8f\t%12.8f\t%12.8f%s%s%s%s%4.3f\n", $2, $3, $4,
 "     XXXX", " 1", "    xx","  " $1"  ", "  0.000"}' $coor)
```

this is where things go wrong

```
 #echos variables and appends to Cmain 
 echo  " $FC   $col" >> Cmain
```

example of what is happening; for some reason it takes the second set of columns and shifts them down, and shifts the first row over...like i said when i do them individually the columns align and everything is peachy...except im missing the first column of data

```
 U1
U2
U3
U4
C1
C2
C3
C4
U5
U6
U7
U8
C5
C6
C7
C8       0.00000000       0.00000000      0.00000000     XXXX 1    xx  U  0.000
   0.00000000     4.43785037      4.86047726     XXXX 1    xx  U  0.000
   4.86047726     0.00000000      4.86047726     XXXX 1    xx  U  0.000
   4.86047726     4.43785037      0.00000000     XXXX 1    xx  U  0.000
   4.86047726     4.43785037      4.86047726     XXXX 1    xx  C  0.000
   4.86047726     0.00000000      0.00000000     XXXX 1    xx  C  0.000
   0.00000000     0.00000000      4.86047726     XXXX 1    xx  C  0.000
   0.00000000     8.87570074      0.00000000     XXXX 1    xx  U  0.000
   0.00000000    13.31355111      4.86047726     XXXX 1    xx  U  0.000
   4.86047726     8.87570074      4.86047726     XXXX 1    xx  U  0.000
   4.86047726    13.31355111      0.00000000     XXXX 1    xx  U  0.000
   4.86047726    13.31355111      4.86047726     XXXX 1    xx  C  0.000
   4.86047726     8.87570074      0.00000000     XXXX 1    xx  C  0.000
   0.00000000    13.31355111      0.00000000     XXXX 1    xx  C  0.000
   0.00000000     8.87570074      4.86047726     XXXX 1    xx  C  0.000
```

~

what i want is

```
  U1    0.00000000     0.00000 etc
  U2    0.00000000     4.43785037      4.86047726 .......
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `paste` command?

Comment: maybe, not sure...my echo command is not working well...so i just need something that will keep the columns aligned and not do as shown

Comment: The `for` loop reveals an apparent misconception of `awk`'s processing model. Your code gets invoked for each line read, top to bottom; so when `awk` is processing line 6, `NR` will be equal to six throughout the script, and when line 7 has been read, the entire script is processed again with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AWK scripts are counting from 6 to 21 for *each* line of each file. I don't think this is necessary. I think what you mean to do is just test to see if the line number is in that range. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
FC=$(awk 'NR >= 6 && NR <=21)
     print $1}' $carf)
```

However, what you really need to do is combine the two AWK scripts, saving the values from the first file in an array and print the values from the array as you print the values from the second file.

```
awk 'FNR == NR && FNR >= 6 && FNR <= 21 {    # first file
        carf[FNR] = $1
     }
     FNR == NR {
         next
     }
     FNR >= 6 && FNR <= 21 {    # second file
         printf  "%-4s%13.8f\t%12.8f\t%12.8f%s%s%s%s%4.3f\n", carf[FNR], $2, $3, $4,
             "     XXXX", " 1", "    xx","  " $1"  ", "  0.000"
     }' "$carf" "$coor"
```

Note that there's no `echo` (or `paste`).

Unless you actually need tabs in your output, you can leave them out and adjust your field widths to give you the output alignment you need.

Comment: ive never used FNR...what does it do exactly?  also, when you are calling carf in printf in the second part what does %-4s do?

Comment: @Sloan: `FNR` is file record number. It's like `NR`, but it resets to 1 at the beginning of each file. It's useful for doing different things for different files as I have done in my answer. When `FNR == NR` you know you're in the first file. The `%-4s` field specification says "a string field 4 characters wide that is left-aligned" (the hyphen signifies left-alignment).

Comment: ahh i think i understand now....um but i am having a small issue with the code. it seems to only be outputting from the $carf file and not doing anything from the $coor file

Comment: @Sloan: It works for me. How are the fields delimited? How many lines are in the file? Can you create a simple test file from scratch and try that?

Comment: i think it was a typo, because i just copied and pasted your code and it worked fine...though it is now bugging me what i did wrong

Comment: ahh i figured it out, when you have FNR == NR {next}; does it matter if those parenthesis/brackets are on the same line as "next"? cause i put them on the different lines like your code and it works like it was supposed too

Comment: @Sloan: No, it should work either way, but the opening curly brace needs to be on the same line as `FNR == NR`

Comment: then there you go, i didnt have the opening brace on the same line as FNR = NR. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`paste`(1)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/) command.  `echo` cannot splice one string into another (which appears to be what you are looking for, really; before each new line in string 2, insert the next line from string 1).

`paste` works on files, not strings, though, but in Bash, that's easy to work around; just use [process substitution](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/process-sub.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Refactored into a function for maintainability and legibility
# Maybe you want to factor out the magical constants 6 and 21 somehow as well?
atoms () {
    awk '# Simplified script; apparently, you simply want lines 6 through 21
     NR==6,NR==21 { print $1 }' "$@"
}
# Ditto
cols () {
    awk '# Simplified this script as well
     NR==6,NR==21 {
       printf  "%13.8f\t%12.8f\t%12.8f%s%s%s%s%4.3f\n", $2, $3, $4,
               "     XXXX", " 1", "    xx","  " $1"  ", "  0.000"}' "$@"
}

paste <(atoms "$carf") <(cols "$coor")
```

If the files are large, you can save a lot of time by quitting after line 21.

```
NR==22 { exit }
```

Comment: so... i dont need for and if statements?... i can just say NR==##, NR==## and that will take me from some beginning line to another line?

Comment: Yeah, the for loop in particular was quite wasteful. The condition is technically similar to an "if" but it's more elegant to use awk's built-in line range selection mechanism.